# .withSession() not working in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create a new session in the Play Framework, but it doesn't seem to stick.

After getting an OpenID result, I want to redirect them back to the index (for now, anyway), along with the OpenID information they just got back.

```
Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession(
            "id" -> info.id,
            "email" -> info.attributes.get("email").getOrElse("unknown@unknown.com"),
            "timestamp" -> (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L).toString)
```

This calls the following function:

```
def index = Action { implicit request ⇒
    Ok(html.index(request))
  }
```

However, the implicit request, according to Eclipse, has null cookies, and a null session. What's going on here?

If it helps, this is the full function that the OpenID information comes from:

```
def openIDCallback = Action { implicit request ⇒
    AsyncResult(
      OpenID.verifiedId.extend(_.value match {
        case Redeemed(info) ⇒ {
          Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession(
            "id" -> info.id,
            "email" -> info.attributes.get("email").getOrElse("unknown@unknown.com"),
            "timestamp" -> (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L).toString)
        }
        case Thrown(t) ⇒ {
          // Here you should look at the error, and give feedback to the user
          Redirect(routes.Application.index)
        }
      }))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the Eclipse debugger does not realize that certain values are lazy. It just says they are null. Meaning, Session *looks* null even though it's not as soon as it is called.

The real problem was, in the part of the code that was supposed to use the Session, I was using request.cookies.get() instead of request.session.get(). Despite a session being a cookie, it's a named cookie with its own, special val. Thus, my code was breaking in a different spot, and for a different reason.